# What is the difference between TO-220F and TO-220FP cases?

Tags: isolation, packages, to220

[Google](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=to-220-fp) search results imply TO-220FP to be full-pack case.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-220#Variations) says that TO-220F is full-pack case.
[Farnell](http://tr.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203047%20110130983%20110163046&No=25&Ns=P_ATT_BASE_VALUE_1002439_EN_GB%7C0&suppressRedirect=true&locale=tr_TR&appliedparametrics=true&getResults=true&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp%3FN%3D203047%26No%3D0%26getResults%3Dtrue%26appliedparametrics%3Dtrue%26locale%3Dtr_TR%26divisionLocale%3Dtr_TR%26catalogId%3D%26skipManufacturer%3Dfalse%26skipParametricAttributeId%3D%26prevNValues%3D203047) categorizes TO-220F and TO-22FP differently.

I'm confused. What is the difference between these two TO-220 case versions?

Comment: Did you check the datasheets for mechanical and thermal specification?

Comment: I have check datasheets of several components. They appear to be same. Both F and FP are isolated. Datasheets don't mention detailed information.

Comment: Package codes often vary between manufacturers.  You will have to study the datasheet of the parts you are interested in to find what that code means to that manufacturer.

Answer (score 9):

The STP12PF06 datasheet (first google hit for 'to-220p to-220fp') shows that the f version has a metal tab, and the fp version has only plastic on the outside (at least at the front, but I assume also on the back).

[image]

This makes it easier to mount the package galvanically isolated, but the plastic layer seems to add some thermal resistance: the rthj-case of the fp version is almost 3 C/W higher.

[image]

Comment: I don't see an F version of [STP12PF06](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/stmicroelectronics_cd00050425.pdf) in the datasheet.